# Does Sql Server CE supports MERGE statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to run a `MERGE` query against a `Sql Server CE` database but it's throwing the error :

```
There was an error parsing the query. ...
```

while the same query is working fine in `Sql Server` .
is `merge statement` not **supported** in `Sql Server CE` at all ? if so , is there any equivalent statement for `CE` ?

```
MERGE [Books] as T 
USING(SELECT 1 S) as S 
ON T.Category ='Fiction' AND T.Lang='En'
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET Title=@Title
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT (Id , Title , Lang , Category) VALUES (@Id , @Title , @Lang , @Category);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MERGE is not supported in SQL Server Compact, you must use a combination of UPDATE and INSERT