# how to insert or update if there is already a record?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

My table has two columns: `Amount` and `Date`

When I am adding new values, I want to update the amount if there is already a record with that date.  If there is not, I want to just insert my new values.

Comment: Please provide the `CREATE` statement of your table.

Answer (score 3):

something like:

```
if exists(select * from table where date = @date)
    update table set amount = @amount where date = @date
else
    insert table (amount, date) select @amount, date
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have at least SQL Server 2008, you could use the [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) keyword.  This keyword was added specifically for cases like yours.  You specify a MERGE clause (basically a join) and then statements telling it how to handle when it does or doesn't find a match.

There's a decent example at the bottom that shows merging between a target table and a source "table" created out of a single row of parameters.  To boil it down a bit, you could use something like:

```
MERGE [TargetTable] AS target -- This is the table we'll be updating
    USING (SELECT @Date) AS source (Date) -- These are the new values
    ON (target.Date = source.Date) -- Here we define how we find a "match"
WHEN MATCHED THEN  -- If the date already exists:
    UPDATE SET Amount = @Amount
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN -- If the date does not already exist:
    INSERT (Date, Amount) VALUES (@Date, Amount)
```

Note that the nested `UPDATE` and `INSERT` clauses do not specify a table.  That is because we already told SQL Server which table to perform those actions on when we defined our target table (the table specified right after the `MERGE` keyword).

**Update:** This functionality is apparently [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091092/does-sql-server-ce-supports-merge-statement) by SQL Server CE, so it will not work in your specific case.  I am leaving this answer here as it may help others attempting to do something similar in the full version of SQL Server.  **For the SQL Server CE solution**, check out [BJury's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21628307/1438242) answer.

Comment: Sadly, [ce doesn't support merge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091092/does-sql-server-ce-supports-merge-statement), but kudos for a really nice explanation of MERGE.

Comment: That is sad.  It's very useful for case like these.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `IF .. NOT EXISTS`, you could assert an UPDATE, and fall back on an insert. This is usually quite a performant `UPSERT` pattern if data generally does exist already.

```
UPDATE MyTable
  SET Amount = @NewAmount
  WHERE Date = @Date;

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
  INSERT INTO MyTable(Amount, Date) VALUES (@NewAmount, @Date);
```

Comment: And it looks like CE doesn't support [@@ROWCOUNT either](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173372.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nhibernate ORM, then you can use SaveOrUpdate session method.